# Scala does not write into MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, scala

I am on Ubuntu 20.04. I want to write some data in Scala to MongoDB. Here's what I have:

```
import org.mongodb.scala.bson.collection.immutable.{Document => MongoDocument}
import org.mongodb.scala.{MongoClient, MongoCollection, MongoDatabase}

object Application extends App {
  val mongoClient: MongoClient = MongoClient()

  // Use a Connection String
  //val mongoClient: MongoClient = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost")

  val database: MongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("mydb")

  val collection: MongoCollection[MongoDocument] = database.getCollection("user")

  val doc: MongoDocument = MongoDocument("_id" -> 0, "name" -> "MongoDB", "type" -> "database",
  "count" -> 1, "info" -> MongoDocument("x" -> 203, "y" -> 102))
  collection.insertOne(doc)

  val documents = (1 to 100) map { i: Int => MongoDocument("i" -> i) }
  collection.insertMany(documents)
}
```

The error (not even an error, INFO level) I get:

> Nov 16, 2020 1:42:08 AM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log

> INFO: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017],
> mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN,
> serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}

And nothing happens to the database. No data appears there. No errors, no insertions into Mongo, nothing.

I used primarily these sources as examples:

https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/2.9/getting-started/quick-tour/

https://blog.knoldus.com/how-scala-interacts-with-mongodb/

MongoDB is up, status is active. Inserting data from the terminal was done successfully. So, the program's behavior I have is strange. I've been searching everywhere on the Internet for the answers but I can't seem to find it. Your help will be appreciated a lot. Thank you!

Comment: So your operations return **Obersever** which haven't been subscribed to anything they simply won't be executed. The simplest solution is to turn them into **Futures** and then adding an `Await` to block that thread until the operation is finished.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, thank you! Yes, that was the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez's help. Here's what I have done so far: added an Observer implementation and a promise. Thanks to this post: [Scala script wait for mongo to complete task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45531210/scala-script-wait-for-mongo-to-complete-task) . That's what I have now:

```
    val mongoClient: MongoClient = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost")
    val database: MongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("mydb")
    val collection: MongoCollection[MongoDocument] = database.getCollection("user")

    val doc: MongoDocument = MongoDocument("name" -> "MongoDB", "type" -> "database",
      "count" -> 1, "info" -> MongoDocument("x" -> 203, "y" -> 102))
    val observable: Observable[Completed] = collection.insertOne(doc)

    val promise = Promise[Boolean]
    observable.subscribe(new Observer[Completed] {

      override def onNext(result: Completed): Unit = println("Inserted")

      override def onError(e: Throwable): Unit = {
        println("Failed")
        promise.success(false)
      }

      override def onComplete(): Unit =  {
        println("Completed")
        promise.success(true)
      }
    })

    val future = promise.future
    Await.result(future, Duration(5, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS))

    mongoClient.close()
```

Generally speaking, it works in most cases. Though, I didn't handle the case with `insertMany` method where the program has to wait for the last element insertion. My realization does not work properly with this.

P.S. Turns out `insertMany` also works fine with this example, I just tested it with the wrong data.